# Can this question be re-opened?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I edited [this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/23988/52433) question, but I'm not sure what the process is to get it re-opened. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done!  Just do what you did and wait for we mods (or several high-rep individuals) to get our acts together. Thank-you for your contribution!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Appreciate the help.